# Хорошая ли идея рисовать сетку с помощью GL?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Для редактора уровней мне нужна сетка (прямоугольная и радиальная), а так же полный контроль над ней изнутри игры, ее цвет, размер, количество внутренних делений каждой клетки и так далее. Можно ли для этого использовать GL?

Как альтернативу можно было бы использовать что-то, что позволяет рассчитать эту сетку, и потом просто ее отображать, не пересчитывая ее и не перерисовывая ее каждый кадр.

Для GL я добавил оптимизацию, которая кэширует сетку, и перерисовывает ее только когда что-то изменяется в настройках, но много времени уходит на отображение всех линий, если их достаточно много.

Comment: Движок же вроде нативно может рисовать сетку на объектах? `Gizmos` называется.

Comment: @aepot, gizmos нужен для дебага, в официальной документации так и написано. + Эта штука нативно не предоставит весь нужный функционал.

Comment: Так вам оно нужно для проектирования чего-то а не для игры, верно? Вы сначала попробуйте с ними разобраться, а потом скажите, чего именно вам не хватает. Какого нужного функционала там нет. А так, подозреваю, что отрисовки всяких кастомных штук можно выполнять в шейдерах.

Comment: @aepot, я вроде указал в вопросе что это мне нужно для игры, а не для дебага в редакторе. Идея с шейдерами была, однако это вызовет много проблем с реализацией, например расчетом того, какая линия сетки должна быть в какой цвет покрашена, в шейдере это должно быть основано на положении пикселя на экране, соответственно придется усложнять и без того сложный алгоритм дополнительными расчетами, а это только прямоугольная сетка, а нужна же ещё и радиальная. Был вариант запекать это как текстуру, размер и разрешение которой совпадают с экранным.

Comment: А что насчет материалов? Сетка же на какой-то поверхности рисуется, даже если поверхность прозрачная. Правда не совсем представляю, если например надо отрисовать таким образом 3Д-пространство сеткой, а не поверхность. По поводу GL возможно у вас медленно происходит, что вы каждую линию рисуете отдельным вызовом. Попробуйте группировать задачи на отрисовку и делайте много линий за один GL вызов. Ну и последнее, что в голову приходит, это кастомная рендер-фабрика.

Comment: @aepot, ваш совет про количество вызовов отрисовки действительно помог, я слишком много раз делал GL.Begin и GL.End, хотя хватает всего одного раза. Напишу ответ о том что так в принципе можно, главное не делать слишком много лишних вызовов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря помощи [@aepot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373567/aepot) выяснилось, что в принципе такой вариант имеет место быть, в случае когда требуется двумерная сетка со комплексным алгоритмом расчета.

В случае использования GL следует очень экономно использовать вызовы, GL.Begin и GL.End, так как они достаточно сильно понижают скорость отрисовки такой сетки.

Так же стоит добавлять оптимизацию расчета – не рассчитывать сетку каждый кадр по новой, а делать это только в случае изменения параметров. Расчеты координат каждой линии кэшируются и при отрисовке просто считываются.

Comment: `GL.Begin` и `GL.End` использовать не надо совсем. Это были обертки для вызовов устаревших `glBegin` `glEnd`.